# is the Sudarshana Homam of relatively recent Gaudiya Vaishnavite origin?

Tags: sudarsana, sudarshana-chakra

the words are

> Sri sudarshana Mula mantraha
> Om Shreem Hreem Kleem
> krushNaaya GovinDaaya Gopeejana vallaBhaaya,
> paRaaya paramapuruShaaya paraMaatmane!
> parakarma mantra yantra tantra oushadha astra shasTraani
> samhara samhara
> mrutyor Mochaya Mochaya
> Om namo bhagavate maHaa sudarshaNaaya
> Deeptre JvaaLaa pareeTaaya
> sarvadiKshobhana kaRaaya
> hum phat brahmane paramJyotishe sahaSraara hum phat (Swaaha:)||

(1) Is this of Gaudiya Vaishnavite origin?  The Sanskrit doesn't look archaic like Shruti literature.

(2) does "Sudarshana" refer to the Sudarshana Chakra or to Krishna?

Comment: It might be a Pancharatrika mantra. Pancharatra is a corpus of Vaishnavite Tantrika texts. All Vaishnave denominations,  especially Srivaishnavas rever these texts.

Comment: what is "archaic" literature supposed to look like in your esteemed opinion ?